# I have this matrix. It is a Gram matrix of some bilinear form on the R^n.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

(1 1/2 1/3 1/4 ... 1/(n-1) 1/n)
(1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5 ... 1/n 1/(n+1))
(1/3 1/4 1/5 1/6 ... 1/(n+1) 1/(n+2))
(1/4 1/5 1/6 1/7 ... 1/(n+2) 1/(n+3))
(...................................)
(1/(n-3) 1/(n-2) 1/(n-1) 1/n ... 1/(2n-5) 1/(2n-4))
(1/(n-2) 1/(n-1) 1/n 1/(n+1) ... 1/(2n-4) 1/(2n-3))
(1/(n-1) 1/n 1/(n+1) 1/(n+2) ... 1/(2n-3) 1/(2n-2))
(1/n 1/(n+1) 1/(n+2) 1/(n+3) ... 1/(2n-2) 1/(2n-1))

I need to prove that it is positive. But I can't complete it.

Comment: sorry for antilatex

Comment: Is that the Hilbert matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes

Comment: So, if is a natural form of matrix, I think it is enough.

Comment: An inner product with this matrix is $\int_0^1p(t)q(t)\,dt$, where $p$ and $q$ are degree $n$ or less polynomials with real coefficients.